# Noncommutative Erlangen Program

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, noncommutative-geometry, homogeneous-spaces

Has Klein's "Erlangen Program" been generalized/extended to the noncommutative setting (say, à la Connes)?  Is there a classification of "noncommutative klein geometries" at least in very low dimension?

Answer (score 2):

Some steps towards generalizing/extending "Erlangen Program" to the noncommutative setting have been taken by V. Kisil. See eg. [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/math-ph/0112059.pdf) and his later papers.